# Is it possible to disable a marker while drawing it on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I am developing an app using **google map api v2**. I have to draw the winds of each region on the map and I have no issues with that. The problem is, wind is completely filling my map and so the intend click on any other marker will go to the wind. Is there a way to disable the click of that particular marker while setting it up?

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("wind"));
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(OthersUtil.getRotatedBitmap(MapActivity.this, ws, windForecasts.get(i).wd)));
```

This is how I add wind markers.The only work around I found was this

```
 @Override
 public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
 if(marker.getTitle().toString().equals("wind")){
                onMapClickListener.onMapClick(marker.getPosition());
            }
}else{
another marker clicked
}
```

[image]

This is what it looks like.In this image I have 2 markers and I don't want the click of winds markers.

There is no `marker.setClickable(false)`.

Comment: No that workaround is not perfect sometimes it's taking the wind click even if I clicked on another marker..I was actually looking for something like this marker.setClickable(false) .But I think it's only there in v3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable just marker click event then use below code:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes I know that but I have different markers as well which need click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

        if (marker.equals(myMarker)) 
        {
            //handle click here
        }
    }
```

i hope it'll help!

Answer (score 0):

I used this way to differentiate the marker:

When you added marker please add this also into **`snippet("wind")`** on Wind marker and pass **`snippet("")`** on another map marker

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker arg0) {
    if (arg0.getSnippet().contains("wind")) {
    } else{
    // Click of another marker
    }
}
```

Comment: It's same as setting the title for different markers right ?
I am checking like this 
if(marker.getTitle().toString().equals("wind")){
}else{
another marker
}

Comment: I know that you did with title and you are getting some isue from it. I did not use title for differentiate.

But I have used snippet and work perfect on every marker. If you are facing the same same issue with this than you have to check where you are passing the title/snippet value as "wind". May be something went wrong there.

Comment: Ah ok understood ..Actually my issue was when 2 markers are close to each other..The click area on the wind image was big and hence always take the click on wind markers.Now I have reduced the click area of wind image and solved the problem..Anyway thanks it was a new info..

Answer (score 0):

You can you use a `Map<Marker, Object>`, with `Object` being anything that represents your data related to a wind marker or other marker, putting them like this:

```
hashMap.put(map.addMarker(MarkerOptions), obj));
```

then retrieve the Object via the map in your `onMarkerClick()`, check if is a "wind object" or not and you're done.